# Using HTML fragments with declarative HTML views

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to decompose a large HTML view down into smaller, more manageable chunks.

Is it possible to use fragments to do this?

For example, I have a fragment file (view.configurator.Summary.fragment.html) containing the following:

```
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Button" data-text="Hello"></div>
```

In my parent file, I try to include the fragment as follows:

```
            <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.VBox" class="summary-panel-content">

                <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.Fragment"
                     data-fragment-name="view.configurator.Summary" 
                     data-type="HTML"></div>

            </div>
```

However I get the following Error in the console:

> Please provide a fragment name

Any ideas?

Seems like its a bug, but you can workaround by wrapping the fragment in a custom control

```
 sap.ui.core.Control.extend("sap.mic.controls.Fragment", {

    metadata: {
        properties: {
            "name": "string"
        }
    },

    init: function () {
    },

    renderer: function (renderManager, control) {
        var fragmentName = control.getProperty("name"),
            fragment = sap.ui.htmlfragment(fragmentName);

        renderManager.renderControl(fragment);
    }
});
```

And used like so:

```
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.m.Page" data-enable-scrolling="false">

    <div data-sap-ui-type="sap.mic.controls.Fragment"
         data-name="view.configurator.Summary"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Lowering the question score since HTML views and HTML fragments are deprecated: [`ef39784`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/ef397849ae0423ad758ca25ac45a16aa18afc789), [`2f98d40`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/2f98d407cd3752e6dcf1fc6e7938202c5db183cf)

Answer (score 6):

**In XML-View**

Include the view with this:

```xml
<mvc:XMLView viewName="your.namespace.ViewName" async="true" />
```

<sup>Whereas `xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"`</sup>

**In HTML-View**

You can include Views like this:

```html
<div data-sap-ui-type="sap.ui.core.mvc.HTMLView" data-view-name="your.namespace.ViewName" data-async="true"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Manuel - thanks for the Answer, However your suggestion uses subviews and not the fragments. Having said that, subview might be the way forward

Comment: Jep, i think this is a bug in openui5/sapui5. Because the properties fragmentName and/or fragmentContent are not registred in metadata as properties. so in declerative support this attributes gets trashed. i don't know if this is the main reason but it looks like. BUT a fragment is just a view without a controller. so, feel free to use it as a view.

Comment: Thanks Manuel, Seems like a bug to me to.

Comment: @GarMaguire Have you guys ever reported this bug on GitHub? Couldn't find it so far. Otherwise, I'll try to report if it's still reproducible.