# How to Include External XML View in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

[Here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.FlexBoxNested/preview) I see how to create a personalized layout by a nested elements.
But if I want to divide each part in an XML view, how can I do it?

I would do something like this:

```
//file1
<page>
  elementA
  elementB
<\page>

//fileA
<page>
  ...
<\page>

//fileB
<page>
  ...
<\page>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199437/using-html-fragments-with-declarative-html-views/22200911#22200911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an XML view just like any other control instead of the core:HTML in the example code.