# How can one insert existing xml view into splitter layout

Tags: xml, sapui5

Can I define `layout` via **xml** and later **reference** and insert that `layout` into `splitter layout` programmatically?

Something similar to inflating layout in **Android** app development?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Please provide an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: My colleague has already made master and detail views for some data as separate pages. Users new request is to show master/details data in a split mode in one page. Is there a way to reuse existing views of master and detail data and insert them in the new page which will have splitter obj?

Comment: So, do you want to use [sap.ui.layout.Splitter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.Splitter/preview) or a [sap.m.SplitContainer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/master-detail/demokit.html#/object/ObjectID_1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `your.package.YourLayout` is an `XMLView`, then here is an example of placing two instances of `YourLayout` inside a `sap.ui.commons.Splitter` within another `XMLView`:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:ui="sap.ui.commons">

    <ui:Splitter>
        <ui:firstPaneContent>
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="your.package.YourLayout" />
        </ui:firstPaneContent>
        <ui:secondPaneContent>
            <mvc:XMLView viewName="your.package.YourLayout" />
        </ui:secondPaneContent>
    </ui:Splitter>
</mvc:View>
```

Source: [Using html fragments with declarative html views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199437/using-html-fragments-with-declarative-html-views/22200911#22200911)